# Generate Delphi XML documentation

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi 10.3, does it's possible to generate XML documentation directly from the IDE ? Like Java with /** + [Enter] to generate Java doc with parameter ?

Answer (score 6):

Delphi already comes with some Live Templates for XMLDOC. F.i. when you type the word *summary* in the editor and press TAB, it will be expanded to a summary XMLDOC comment. There are other templates named *para*, *param* and *remarks*.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know Java system, but with Delphi (Don't know in which version it was introduced), you have to set "Generate XML documentation" in the project options (Building / Delphi Compiler / Compiling / Other options). And also "XML documentation output directory".

The compiler-generated XML documentation is created from the internal representation that the compiler uses for classes, methods, variables, and so on.

You can introduce XML Documentation Comments in your source code:

```
/// <summary> Removes the specified item from the collection
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Item">The item to remove
/// </param>
/// <param name="Collection">The group containing the item
/// </param>
/// <remarks>
/// If parameter "Item" is null, an exception is raised.
/// <see cref="EArgumentNilException"/>
/// </remarks>
/// <returns>True if the specified item is successfully removed;
/// otherwise False is returned.
/// </returns>
function RemoveItem(Item: Pointer; Collection: Pointer): Boolean;
begin
  // Non-XML DOC comment
  // ...
end;
```

Comment: See [XML Documentation for Delphi Code](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/XML_Documentation_for_Delphi_Code) and [XML Documentation Comments](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/XML_Documentation_Comments) in Embarcadero's DocWiki for more details.

Comment: Yes but I dont want to have the XML documentation for all, but only the method I want. I can write comment in summary, but i would like to have param and return generate automatically